# Compiling a Fortran program with netCDF and Intel Fortran on Windows 10

Tags: windows, fortran, netcdf, intel-fortran, netcdf4

I have some Fortran code which uses netCDF for reading and writing files on Linux. On Linux based systems I build netcdf-c, hdf5 & zlib.

Attempting to build on Windows, I have ifort ( 19.1.0.166 ) and Visual Studio 2019 installed and [netCDF-C 4.7.3 ( netCDF-4 64 bit )](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/winbin.html)

I have adapted the call from the Makefile used on Linux as below.

```
>ifort -I"C:\Program Files\netCDF 4.7.3\include" /O2 /real-size:64 /Qdiag-disable:5117 /Qopenmp src\unptrackmod.f90 src\readSSMmod.f90 src\calcConnectivity.f90 src\unptrack.F90 src\readwritenc.f90 "C:\Program Files\netCDF 4.7.3\lib\hdf5.lib" "C:\Program Files\netCDF 4.7.3\lib\netcdf.lib"
```

Which results in:

```
src\readwritenc.f90(7): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [NETCDF]
      use netcdf
----------^
src\readwritenc.f90(35): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NF90_OPEN]
        status = nf90_open(path = filename, mode = nf90_nowrite, ncid = ncid)
-----------------^
src\readwritenc.f90(36): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NF90_NOERR]
        if (status .ne. nf90_noerr) call handle_nf_err(status)
------------------------^
src\readwritenc.f90(39): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NF90_INQ_VARID]
          status = nf90_inq_varid(ncid, "nbe", varid)
-------------------^
src\readwritenc.f90(41): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NF90_GET_VAR]
        status = nf90_get_var(ncid, varid, nbe)
```

The source for the program that I am attempting to compile is [available here](https://github.com/gillibrandpa/unptrack)

Is it necessary to build netCDF from source on Windows to be able to read and write netCDF files from Fortran?

### Further detail

After compiling netCDF-c with CMake and running Visual Studio as Administrator 
, netCDF was installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\netCDF\` with a netcdf.dll written to the include directory and a netcdf.lib in the lib directory.

Assigning these paths to the netcdf-fortran entries (NETCDF_C_INCLUDE_DIR, NETCDF_C_LIBRARY, NETCDF_INCLUDE_DIR) in the CMake-gui, reconfigure and generating the Visual Studio solution again.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: netcdff, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>nf_v2compat.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ncerr referenced in function c_ncabor
1>nf_v2compat.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ncopts referenced in function c_ncgopt
1>C:\netcdf-fortran\fortran\Release\netcdff.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I deleted `nf_v2compat.c` to get rid of the errors above and the INSTALL build succeeds with NC4F, writing `bin\netcdff.dll` & `include\netcdf.inc` files. I added the `NC4F\bin` & lib paths to 'Additional Library Directories' in Linker > Input & netcdff.dll to 'Additional Dependencies' and include path to Additional Include Directories, but the original compilation errors still occur.

Running dumpbin /exports netcdff.dll returns:

```
Dump of file netcdff.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        1000 .text
```

Which I understand to mean it is being built incorrectly.

Although not an answer to my original question, I eventually used Cygwin with gfortran to build the dependencies.

Comment: I believe that it will be necessary for you to build the Fortran NetCDF libraries for Windows from source, unless, that is, you have been able to download a binary for Windows that is ABI compatible with your compiler.  If I remember rightly the NetCDF/Fortran depends on NetCDF/C - have you already built that, or have you downloaded a binary for that ?

Comment: I downloaded the [source for netcdf-fortran from GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran) and ran CMake, `Configure`, then `Generate`, CMake indicates it is linking against `C:/Program Files/netCDF 4.7.3/lib/netcdf.lib` but when I open the project in Visual Studio and attempt to build the solution I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\fortran\Release\netcdff.lib`. It is not clear to me where that path is coming from.

Comment: So I guess `netcdff.lib` is the NetCDF library for Fortran ?  Have you conducted an extensive search of your disks for that lib ?

Comment: I think you are right, looking at the `~/local/lib/` directory under the Windows subsystem for Linux where it is successfully installed there is a series of files named libnetcdff with a number of extensions ( .a, .la, .so, .so.7, .so.7.0.0 ). When attempting to build the INSTALL project in the NC4F.sln in Visual Studio, there is an `error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file. Check INCLUDE paths. [NETCDF]`, I have added the `C:\Program Files\netCDF 4.7.3\` lib and include directories to the Library Directories & Include Directories of the Property Pages > VC++ Directories.